# What is the easy way of implementing Paging in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Being new to ASP.NET MVC, I would like to know the easy method of paging. The data is IQueryable type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var dataPage = data.Skip(pageNumber * pageSize - pageSize).Take(pageSize);
```

To learn the basic tricks of ASP.NET MVC, I suggest reading the free [Professional ASP.NET MVC 1.0 Book Chapter 1 by Scott Guthrie](http://aspnetmvcbook.s3.amazonaws.com/aspnetmvc-nerdinner_v1.pdf)

Comment: Shouldn't the first .Take be .Skip ?

Comment: @Joel: I had just updated it before your comment, refresh to see.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I spoke with Scott (author of that chapter/book) and he is working on several revisions that will go into the actual book, so I highly recommend buying it, if it's within your means.  :-)

Comment: @Jack: What sort of revisions? Total rewrites? I've reported several simple mistakes to him that are fixed in the current revision.

Comment: Note that Skip(0) is not free. http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/06/10/38313/ Hence this incurs a performance penalty for the first (and most commonly requested) page  in both EF and L2S 4.0.

Answer (score 4):

I've been using [this PagedList type](http://www.squaredroot.com/post/2008/07/08/PagedList-Strikes-Back.aspx), originally developed by Rob Conery, and enhanced by Troy Goode. I've even written [extension methods which make it work with jqGrid](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/04/15/38212/). For sheer ease of use, I don't think you're going to beat it.